# Ubuntu live CD struck on loading screen!please help.. I'm dying

Tags: live-cd

I tried to load latest  live CD on my laptop.. But it got struck up on loading screen.. Nothings working.. Not even power button.. I'm quite tensed now! Please help

Comment: Did you already try all the [boot options](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions), especially the [common kernel options](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Common_Kernel_Options) to fix these types of problems? Or maybe your laptop's just broken?